# Does flask cors and jwt extended work together

Tags: flask, flask-jwt-extended, flask-cors

I am having the following error from the below function. If I remove jwt_required, it does work, so I am guessing CORS is allowing access. What could be the issue?

```
@app.route('/user_authentication/protected', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin(headers=['Content-Type','Authorization'])
@jwt_required
def protected():
    # username = get_jwt_identity()
    username = "sana ne "
    # response send to Vue page
    response = {}
    response['user'] = username
    print(response)
    return jsonify(response), 200
```

```
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2022 07:40:30] "POST /user_authentication/protected HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ed\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2088, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\ed\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\ed\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask_cors\extension.py", line 165, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "C:\Users\ed\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\ed\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1515, in full_dispatch_request  
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\ed\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask_cors\extension.py", line 165, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "C:\Users\ed\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1513, in full_dispatch_request  
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\ed\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1499, in dispatch_request       
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\ed\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask_cors\decorator.py", line 128, in wrapped_function
    resp = make_response(f(*args, **kwargs))
TypeError: wrapper() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fn'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using `flask-jwt-extended` > `v4.0.0`. One breaking change was to move all view decorators to a single decorator, which is a callable that returns a decorator. For this reason brackets are required. Try using `jwt_required()`